# Why doesn't SOUND_COMPLETE event fired when starting playback from sound.length position?

Tags: actionscript-3

I realized that Event.SOUND_COMPLETE event isn't fired when starting playback from the sound.length position (it can be used when implementing scrubber: user can seek to 100% and start playing).

Is this bug? What is the common practice to workaround it?

Sample code reproducing this behavior:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

private var sound:Sound;
private var channel:SoundChannel;

public function test():void {
    sound = new Sound();
    sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, testLoadingCompleteHandler);
    sound.load(new URLRequest("/song.mp3"));
}

private function testLoadingCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    // SOUND_COMPLETE doesn't fire when we start playing from sound.length position
    trace("# testSoundLoadingCompleteHandler()");
    channel = sound.play(sound.length);

    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, testPlaybackCompleteHandler);
}

private function testPlaybackCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    // This message won't be printed because SOUND_COMPLETE event isn't fired
    trace("# testPlaybackCompleteHandler()");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe sound.play(sound.length) does not starts playback, or even returns error. I suppose it may be because sound.length is bigger than allowed value. Like in arrays you cannot use array[array.length], because it will be out of range.

I recomend triyng array.length-1

Comment: I've just tested what sound.play(sound.length) returns. It returns SoundChannel as it should.

Currently I start playing from (sound.length - 1) millisecond, as you suggested - it works fine. Thanks.